# Laravel php: unique update validation while editing how to ignore it in updating method

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, backend

i want to ignore the "unique validation" when updating form, want it only when creating

here is rules in Request folder i passed the 'id' to ignore it when updating for 'mobile' field and 'email' field

```
  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'logo' => 'required_without:id|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'category_id'=>'required|exists:main_categories,id',
            'mobile' =>'required|max:100|unique:vendors,mobile,'.$this -> id,
            'email'  => 'required|email|unique:vendors,email,'.$this -> id,
            'password'=>'required_without:id',
            'address'=>'required|string|max:300',

        ];
    }
```

but there is no any efffect
[unique validat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjeEf.jpg)

this controller update method

```
     public function update($id, VendorsRequest $request){
       // return $request;
        //validation
        //update

       try{
           $vendor= vendors::Selection()->find($id);
           if(!$vendor)
               return redirect()->route('admin.vendors')->with(['error' => 'المتجر دا مش موجود ممكن تجرب مرة تانية']);
           DB::beginTransaction();
           if($request->has('logo')) {
               $filepath = uploadImage('vendors', $request->logo);
               vendors::where('id', $id)
               ->update([
                   'logo' => $filepath,

               ]);
           }
           $data= $request-> except('_token','id','logo','password');
           if($request->has('password')){
               $data['password'] = $request->password;
           }
           vendors::where('id',$id)
           -> update($data);

            DB::commit();
            return redirect()->route('admin.vendors')->with(['success' => 'تم التحديث بنجاح']);


       }catch (\Exception $ex){
            DB::rollBack();

            return $ex;
        }
```

this is route

```
Route::prefix('vendors')
    ->group(function(){
        Route::get('/', [VendorsController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.vendors');
        Route::get('create', [VendorsController::class, 'create'])->name('admin.vendors.create');
        Route::post('store', [VendorsController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.vendors.store');
        Route::get('edit/{id}', [VendorsController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.vendors.edit');
        Route::post('update/{id}', [VendorsController::class, 'update'])->name('admin.vendors.update');
        Route::get('delete/{id}', [VendorsController::class, 'destroy'])->name('admin.vendors.delete');
```

selection of table's field

```
 public function ScopeSelection($query){
    return $query -> select('id','name','logo','mobile','address','email','password','category_id','active','created_at','updated_at');
}
```

i need help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using your VendorsRequest request handler for both create and update.

The simplest way to solve this is to write a VendorsUpdateRequest handler and do not include the unique options.

Another option would be to move the validation into your controller check which method you are using create or update and return the rules you want for that option.

Comment: Thanks a lot I created VendorsUpdateRequest , but is there any way to make a request rules for both create and update method, and except the unique validation iwhen updating

Comment: @Diab_Diab the best way to do that would be to bring the validation into the controller as a rules() method.  Then pass a flag to that method to control which items are in the rules array.